# Manage requests to unsubscribe

Tags: email, gmail, tracking

**Executive Summary**

Is there a tool to track unsubscribe requests made via gmail?  E.G. If "Bob's subpar Recruiting firm" shoots me an email, is there a tool that can help me track the fact that I unsubscribed from their emails and how many attempts I've made to unsubscribe?

E.G.

```
#agency:  "Bob's subpar recruiting firm"
#unsubscribeAttemps:  10
```

**Details**

I'm being overwhelmed with recruiter emails.  On an average day my email is hit with 15 emails from recruiters.  Most of these are positions I would never even consider and if they read my resume then I shouldn't have received it.  I click unsubscribe and sometimes it works, but mostly it does not work.

At least this way I can manage the worst offenders.  If I contact them directly maybe I can prevent throwing my email address away every 2-3 years.

Or, if there is a better tool then I'm all ears.

Comment: You may have use for generic anti-spam tools such as a Bayesian spam filter.

Comment: Yup. That's what I do. It's simple enough to do, doesn't take much time, and it is effective. I also use [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en_GB) on my Android 'phone and block them from calling me

Comment: Can't you just create a Gmail filter to delete emails from Bob without reading them (move straight to trash)? That works for me

Answer (score 1):

Unsubscribe requests do not work all the time. Legitimate companies might honor them, while shady businesses - the very ones you want to avoid - will just use the unsubscribe request to confirm that your email is used and to send you even more spam.

You should instead blacklist the offending sending address on your mailclient or webmail (practically all of them have this feature).